# Trouble lighting and extinguishing an LED based on the contents of a variable in Python 2

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

I'm working on a weather station that draws from Environment Canada data for Toronto. If the wind speed and wind chill results exceeds or falls below certain numbers, I want to light LEDs on a breadboard.

The wind speed warning works correctly using the following code:

```
if ((cityObject.get_quantity(wind)) > windmax: GPIO.output(13,GPIO.HIGH)
else: GPIO.output(13,GPIO.LOW)
```

The wind chill warning is proving more complex. Environment Canada returns a "None" when there is no discernible wind chill. But, eventually, it will also return a negative integer instead. The following code lights my wind chill warning LED when, really, it should be off:

```
chillzero = "None"

if (cityObject.get_quantity(chill)) == chillzero: GPIO.output(11,GPIO.LOW)

if (cityObject.get_quantity(chill)) < chillmax: GPIO.output(11,GPIO.HIGH)
else: GPIO.output(11,GPIO.LOW)
```

At time of writing, the following returns None

```
print cityObject.get_quantity(chill)
```

Any idea why this code is causing my LED to stay illuminated? I only want it to come on when the wind chill is below `-15C`.

Comment: By None do you mean the type `None`, or the string `"None"`?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. This is literally my first coding project of any kind. The print function returns "None" (no quotes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem in this case was Python not treating the wind chill result from Environment Canada as an integer, despite the resulting containing numbers. This code fixed it.

```
chillmax = int(cityObject.get_quantity(chill))
    if (cityObject.get_quantity(chill)) is not None:
        if chillmax < -15:
            GPIO.output(11,GPIO.HIGH)
       else:
            GPIO.output(11,GPIO.LOW)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're confusing the string `"None"` and the type `None`.

`print cityObject.get_quantity(chill)` will print the type representation of `None` so that is why you'll see None printed.

Instead of:

```
if (cityObject.get_quantity(chill)) == chillzero:
```

try just:

```
if cityObject.get_quantity(chill) is not None:
```

Also there appears to be some redunant calls, so you could also try this:

```
if (cityObject.get_quantity(chill)) < chillmax:
    print "Windchill: %s" % cityObject.get_quantity(chill)
    GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)
else:
    # Would be greater than or equal to chillmax, or return None
    GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: What if it returns `0` instead of `None`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Appreciate the quick answer. Unfortunately, knocking out "== chillzero" still causes the LED to light up.

Comment: You probably want `is not None`

Comment: Thank you both. Should I keep what's after the semicolon? So: if (cityobject.get_quantity(chill)) is not None: GPIO.output(11,GPIO.LOW)

Comment: Yes, that _should_ go on a newly indented line though.

Comment: Gah! The LED is still coming on.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. Rebooted and it appears to have cleared. Thank you both. Using "is not" will cause the light to come on if there is any wind chill value, correct? Any ideas about how I would tell the LED to come on only if it's colder than -15 out?

Comment: Could you try that last snipped I've posted in my answer?

Comment: Thanks Jacob and Peter. Glad you stuck with this problem. Unfortunately, something in the code is still triggering the wind chill LED. Peter's solution keeps the LED at bay, but I imagine it will activate with any wind chill value, when I really want it only on when it's colder than -15. Jacob's extra code to clear up redundant calls triggers the LED in error for some reason. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your first coding project of any kind, it seems like you might just have a datatype issue somewhere. When in doubt, just do it step by step excruciatingly if need be.

```
try:
    chill_value=cityObject.get_quantity(chill)
    print "Windchill is: "+str(chill_value)
except:
    print "Unable to get chill value for some reason."
    exit(1)

try:
    if (float(chill_value) < float(chillmax)):
        print "Turning on LED"
        GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)
    else:
        print "Turning off LED"
        GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)
except:
    #It should not make it here unless one of your values is not a
    #float, or you have some other issue with being able to compare
    #the values.
    print "Unable to compare chill value. Defaulting to off."
    GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)
```